# how to merge 1d array into 2d array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have 2 arrays with different dimensions, and how to merge my one dimension array to two dimension array, here is my 2 array look like

this is my two dimension array

```
array (
0 => 
array (
'id' => 1,
'alias' => 'Anderson',
'location' => 'Semarang',
    'up' => 39144,
'status' => 'DOWN',
),
```

and this is my one dimension array

```
 array (
  'last_accessed_by' => 1,
  'last_refresh' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
   'created_at' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
 )
```

this is what i expect from merging the arrays

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'alias' => 'Anderson',
    'location' => 'Semarang',
    'up' => 39144,
    'status' => 'DOWN',
    'last_accessed_by' => 1,
    'last_refresh' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
    'created_at' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
  ),
```

Comment: im using laravel so thats the dd output from,

Comment: `$data=json_decode($response,true);` this is the array coming from, i'm not input it, just decode from response

Comment: i just edited my posts

Comment: Please make every attempt to progress all of your questions toward a system recognized resolution (simply put, when you receive at least one answer that solves your issue, please award the green tick to the best answer).

Comment: thanks anyway for correcting my posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the `[0]` element of the first array and the whole second array like this...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dDGag))

```
$array1 = array (
    array (
        'id' => 1,
        'alias' => 'Anderson',
        'location' => 'Semarang',
        'up' => 39144,
        'status' => 'DOWN'
    )
);

$array2 =  array (
    'last_accessed_by' => 1,
    'last_refresh' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
    'created_at' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39'
);
$array1[0] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2);
// or because merging associative arrays, if you aren't scared of array union operators:
// $array1[0] += $array2;
//            ^^-- this merges the 2nd to [0] of the 1st without a function call

var_export($array1);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'alias' => 'Anderson',
    'location' => 'Semarang',
    'up' => 39144,
    'status' => 'DOWN',
    'last_accessed_by' => 1,
    'last_refresh' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
    'created_at' => '2018-10-29 00:21:39',
  ),
)
```

Comment: this is exactly what i looking for, thanks a lot for help,

Comment: I would like to upvote your question, but my StackOverflow Good Citizenship principles disallow it while your question does not contain a coding attempt.  If you add this, please let me know and I'll come back.